# USB Ports not Recognizing Devices?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, usb, ati, 64-bit

I have a particularly odd problem, that I can't seem to solve. I recently just booted Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to my Desktop, the strange thing about it is, that only the USB 3.0 ports on the front recognize my Devices.
I am stumped I've looked every where on this forum and others for the answer, and none of them seem to have my specific problem.

## Desktop Specifications:

- x64 Bit
- Gigabyte Motherboard AM3+ Socket
- AMD FX 8320 8-Core Clocked at 3.5 GHz
- 16 Gigabytes of RAM
- 2 Gigabytes of VRAM
- Radeon HD 8500 Graphics Card
- 7.1 Surround Sound Card
- Built-In Ethernet 10/100
- 12 USB 2.0 Ports
- 4 USB 3.0 Ports

I'm lost as too how my machine won't get everything recognized.
Note: I am running the x64 Version

Comment: None of the 2.0 USB ports work? Absolutely 0? Have you checked if it's not a hardware problem? (Perhaps by installing another OS?)

Comment: Windows 7 has absolutely no problems. It's just Ubuntu, :( and yes none of the USB 2.0's work. :|

Comment: Do they all work when you boot from a 13.04 or [13.10](http://releases.ubuntu.com/saucy/) Live DVD? If they do, it might be a kernel issue. Also double check your BIOS/EUFI settings.

Comment: Let me go check, I just downloaded and made a live usb. Hopefully it will boot. Also My BIOS/UEFI Have no problems seeing them either.

Comment: I've been tinkering with the tons of bios options and nothing. Also the Live USB Route failed. I just had to try it. :| Well now I'm going to try a live DVD like -* searchfgold6789 *- suggested.

Comment: It's seems that only certain ports work. I can use my devices but only in certain ports. It's rather strange, I have only 4 ports that work, and I have over 16 on my machine. :/